# Batch script help request: How to find a line break?

Tags: batch-file, find, findstr

I have a bunch of RAR files containing JPGs and I am trying to get the name of the first file of each RAR file.

For example, if I run `7z l -r abc.rar`, I would like to get the first file `01.jpg`

```
path = xyz.rar
Type = zip
Physical Size = 15430338

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2003-03-06 13:32:44 ....A       330433       325405  01.jpg
2003-03-06 13:34:08 ....A       301098       291857  02.jpg
2003-03-06 13:34:14 ....A       257770       244619  03.jpg
2003-03-06 13:34:22 ....A       301220       292019  04.jpg
2003-03-06 13:34:30 ....A       326989       316380  05.jpg
```

So far, with the following batch script, I am able to strip the metadata of the 7z command and get the file list in the `contents.txt` file.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"

for %%f in ("*.*") do (
    echo "%%f" >> contents.txt
    echo.

    7z l -r "%%f" | FIND /V "ing " | FIND /V "Igor Pavlov" | FIND /V "--" | FIND /V "Path" | FIND /V "Type" | FIND /V "Solid" | FIND /V "Blocks" | FIND /V "Multivolume" | FIND /V "Volumes" | FIND /V "Date" | FIND /V "---" | FIND /V "Physical Size" | FINDSTR /R /E ".jpg" >> contents.txt

    echo.
)
PAUSE
```

Example output:

```
"abc.rar" 
2003-03-26 01:18:50 ....A       331711       330648  01.jpg
2003-03-26 01:18:54 ....A       271173       270942  02.jpg

"xyz.rar" 
2003-07-08 22:40:56 ....A       445799       430058  p00.jpg
2003-07-08 22:40:40 ....A       181324       142554  p01.jpg
2003-07-08 22:40:42 ....A       384901       370140  p02.jpg

"efg.rar" 
2003-07-08 22:42:54 ....A       156436       115275  xy01abc.jpg
2003-07-08 22:42:58 ....A       456633       448240  xy02abc.jpg
2003-07-08 22:42:58 ....A       355114       339026  xy03abc.jpg
2003-07-08 22:42:58 ....A       355114       339026  xy04abc.jpg
```

I think if I tweak my script to find the first line break followed by ".jpg" in the 7z output, I can get the first file name in the following format:

```
"abc.rar" 
2003-03-26 01:18:50 ....A       331711       330648  01.jpg

"xyz.rar" 
2003-07-08 22:40:56 ....A       445799       430058  p00.jpg

"efg.rar" 
2003-07-08 22:42:54 ....A       156436       115275  xy01abc.jpg
```

But I don't know how to search for line break in the **FINDSTR** command. I tried to find for ".jpg\n" in **FINDSTR**:

```
7z l -r "%%f" | FIND /V "ing " | FIND /V "Igor Pavlov" | FIND /V "--" | FIND /V "Path" | FIND /V "Type" | FIND /V "Solid" | FIND /V "Blocks" | FIND /V "Multivolume" | FIND /V "Volumes" | FIND /V "Date" | FIND /V "---" | FIND /V "Physical Size" | FINDSTR /R /E ".jpg\n" >> contents.txt
```

But it didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

My desired output is to strip all the date and file size information from the file name output and add it after the RAR file name, such as:

```
"abc.rar" 01.jpg

"xyz.rar" p00.jpg

"efg.rar" xy01abc.jpg
```

There is no fixed pattern of the first jpg file. Some start with 00, some with 01, some with text and number (example x00y.jpg). I've tried various methods to search for file names that start with 00 or 01 with and without text (example, in my command I used  `FINDSTR /R /E "[a-z][0-1]*.jpg"` to search for file names with text and number, but there are some RAR files with no text in file names).

Answer (score 1):

Executing in a command prompt window `findstr /?` outputs help for this command listing and explaining `/E` to search for the specified string at end of the lines. Using this option is much easier than everything else to find a string at end of a line.

---

One possible batch solution for your task could be:

```
@echo off
del contents.txt 2>nul
for %%A in ("*.*") do call :GetFirstFileName "%%~A"
exit /B

:GetFirstFileName
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%~1" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I "/C:.jpg">"%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
for /F "usebackq eol=` tokens=5* delims= " %%B in ("%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp") do (
    echo "%~1" %%C>>contents.txt
    del "%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
    exit /B
)
del "%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
exit /B
```

This batch file calls **7-Zip** for each file in current directory to list the archive contents which is filtered by **findstr** to get into temporary list file just the lines ending with `.jpg` in any case.

The temporary list file is processed by a **FOR** loop to get just the file name from first line written together with archive file name into contents text file.

---

Another solution would be using **FOR** directly to process list output of **7-Zip**.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
del contents.txt 2>nul
for %%A in ("*.*") do call :GetFirstFileName "%%~A"
endlocal
exit /B

:GetFirstFileName
set "NextLine=0"
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%~1">"%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
for /F "usebackq eol=` tokens=1,5* delims= " %%B in ("%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp") do (
    if "%%B" == "-------------------" (
        set "NextLine=1"
    ) else if "!NextLine!" == "1" (
        echo "%~1" %%D>>contents.txt
        del "%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
        exit /B
    )
)
del "%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
exit /B
```

This batch file calls **7-Zip** for each file in current directory to list the archive contents redirected into a temporary list file.

The temporary list file is processed by a **FOR** loop to get just the file name from first line after a line containing `-------------------` written together with archive file name into contents text file.

The number of lines above the list is not constant which is the reason why **FOR** option `skip=` can't be used here.

It does not matter which extension first file in archive file has for this batch solution.

---

One more solution is using free **UnRAR** to get first file name of each RAR archive file.

```
@echo off
del contents.txt 2>nul
for %%A in ("*.rar") do call :GetFirstFileName "%%~A"
exit /B

:GetFirstFileName
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" lb "%~1">"%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
for /F "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%B in ("%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp") do (
    echo "%~1" %%B>>contents.txt
    del "%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
    exit /B
)
del "%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"
exit /B
```

The advantage is that **UnRAR** supports several options for list format including a bare format used when using command `l` with `b` appended. This makes getting first file name much easier.

---

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" -?`
- `"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" /?`